# Looking for alternatives to Google's business email solution

Tags: email, google, web-hosting

I'm planning on hosting some websites and am trying to figure out the best way to handle emails for my clients.  I don't want to have to set up a whole email system.

I've seen Google's apps for business email solution (http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) but its $5/month per person.

Are there any alternatives out there to Google's solution?

Comment: belongs on web masters.

Comment: How many users? If it's a large number, it might affect what options are more viable for your situation.

Comment: Less than 2-3 thousand.  What are you thinking?

Comment: If you need to allow public sign-up then that'll also change your options a bit. And is your priority on usability, spam protection, security, extensibility/compatibility, or price? Google probably has all other options beat for the first 4 criteria. There's a ton of cross-integration amongst Google Apps, as well as 3rd-party apps/services.

Answer (score 1):

Google apps is free up to 10 users, and otherwise i'd still recommend the google apps even if you have to pay for it.
it most likely will have a higher availability than most of the other solutions and works perfectly with all stuff like smartphones. Ofcourse there''s also the part where the users are quite often used to gmail so they would prefer it instead of something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found so long as you have cPanel set up with the hosting environment that handling email that is managed by the web server isn't too bad.  It can be configured on multiple devices and can offer a web front end.

Comment: Are you talking about a web front-end like roundcube?

Comment: I believe that is one of the standard options, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

did you check http://domains.live.com/ it has a free service ( up to 100 email accounts per domain )